# How's dijkstra algorithm with array as a data structure for the priority queue instead of a heap?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

Can you please rigorously describe the algorithm of Dijkstra for the calculation of the shortest paths from s to all other nodes of the graph (SPT) which uses an unordered array both for managing the priority queue (not the Heap structure) and for all
other data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Dykstra's algorithm gives you all the shortest paths from your beginning node to every other node in the graph. If throughout the course of the algorithm you keep track of all these paths in addition to just their weights, you'll get what you want. -Alex R. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998848/can-i-use-dijkstras-algorith-for-finding-all-shortest-paths)

By using an unordered array, you will have to traverse it a lot, raising the complexity to O( V^2 ) from O(E + V log V).